# How to display section number in the section's title?

Tags: sectioning

Is there an easy way to display a section's number in its title? I am currently using the `article` document class.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}

    Introduction text here...

\section{Item 1: What is Quantitative Finance?}
Indeed, before actually studying a topic, we should start by having a good definition of what we are studying. So what is quantitative finance?

\section{Item 2: Geometric Brownian Motion}
blalblabla

\end{document}
```

By default the section numbers appear in front of the section's title. Instead I would like to have the section number appear inside the document's title after the word "Item" and be incremented automatically (so that I don't need to keep a manual count of the Item numbers).

Comment: Only the sections ? Or `\subsection` etc as well?

Comment: I can have \subsection s but they will not be numbered. I only need the numbering at the section level after the word "Item"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You mean something like this? Using `titlesec` will make automatically every section use the "Item xx" value.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries}{Item \thesection:\ }{0pt}{}

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}

    Introduction text here...

\section{What is Quantitative Finance?}
Indeed, before actually studying a topic, we should start by having a good definition of what we are studying. So what is quantitative finance?

\section{Geometric Brownian Motion}
blalblabla

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

No package usage here, just slightly redefining `\@seccntformat` and checking with `\pdfstrcmp` whether it is `section` or another level.

`\pdfstrcmp` is a primitive provided by `pdftex` and `pdflatex`, so it is a built-in command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\makeatletter
\let\@seccntformatorig\@seccntformat
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \ifnum0=\pdfstrcmp{#1}{section}%
  Item \csname the#1\endcsname:{} %Well, could say Item \thesection:{} here as well... 
  \else
  \@seccntformatorig{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}




\section*{Introduction}

    Introduction text here...

\section{What is Quantitative Finance?}
Indeed, before actually studying a topic, we should start by having a good definition of what we are studying. So what is quantitative finance?

\subsection{Foo}


\section{Geometric Brownian Motion}
blalblabla

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

No packages and the possibility of doing different things for different levels. Here I define `\formatsection` to add **Item n:** and `\formatsubsection` to do **Subitem n.m:**, whereas the standard output is used for `\subsubsection`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname format#1\endcsname
    \csname format#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\formatsection}{Item \thesection: }
\newcommand{\formatsubsection}{Subitem \thesubsection: } % just for example

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}

Introduction text here...

\section{What is Quantitative Finance?}

Indeed, before actually studying a topic, we should start by 
having a good definition of what we are studying. So what is 
quantitative finance?

\subsection{This is a subsection}

Here we have text.

\subsubsection{This is a subsubsection}

Here we have text.

\section{Geometric Brownian Motion}

blalblabla

\end{document}
```

[image]